# Почему при клике на элемент не появляется список?

Tags: javascript

При клике на любой элемент списка должен появляться вложенный список но этого не происходит, не могу понять в чем причина
[Полный код](https://codepen.io/DmitriyYaroshchuk/pen/vYzYmGO)

```js
const menu = document.getElementById('menu');
menu.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    if (event.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
        const currentParent = event.target.parentNode;
        console.log(currentParent);
        document.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach((activeParent) => {
            if (activeParent !== currentParent) {
                activeParent.classList.toggle('active', activeParent.contains(currentParent));
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто до банальности, Вы просто забыли дописать еще одну строчку после цикла, а именно ту которая будет открывать ваше меню. Возможно вы хотели обойтись одним циклом, тогда ошибка в Вашей логике — в этот цикл не попадает элемент который Вы хотите открыть (он должен быть `.active`) уже открытым.

```
  const menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  menu.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
          const currentParent = event.target.parentNode;
          console.log(currentParent);
          document.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach((activeParent) => {
              if (activeParent !== currentParent) {
                  activeParent.classList.toggle('active', activeParent.contains(currentParent));
              }
          })
          currentParent.classList.toggle('active'); // <---- это откроет
      }
  })
```

Comment: @NANO_996 Вот поэтому стоит писать код самому и вдумчиво )